# Encoding arabic using UTF8

Tags: php, html, encoding, arabic

Currently I created simple website using include system

1. header.php - contains first part of HTML page (Head, meta tags, JS codes ... etc )
2. page.php - contains simple php code

   page content

My main problem with arabic language

I have to put

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

in page.php, footer.php  between `<head>` tags otherwise the arabic will not support correctly.

This prevents page validation because of these tags.

Is there any method to avoid this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
  // Send a raw HTTP header 
  header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 

  // Declare encoding META tag, it causes browser to load the UTF-8 charset 
  // before displaying the page. 
  echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'; 

  // Right to Left issue 
  echo '<body dir="rtl">';
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Encode the arabic string into UTF-8 using a tool [like this](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=none&action=encode&charset=utf_8). (No need to change any settings - that link has the the correct settings you need).
2. Then use utf8_decode() to decode the string back.

Example:

```
<?php echo utf8_decode('your_encoded_string_goes_here'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all of the answers... Make sure your (HTML/PHP) files  are saved with the right encoding utf-8

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to put this

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in a file that you include/include_once in your pages

**EDIT. example:**

*header.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>my title in العربية</title>
  </head>
  <body>
```

*mypage.php*

```
<?php
include_once 'header.html';
?>

<p>
العربية
</p>

<?php 
include 'foot.html';
?>
```

*foot.html*

```
<div>my footer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to do it? can you give me example ?

Answer (score 0):

1- Put this

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

2- You should also save the documents in UTF-8 not ANSI

Answer (score 0):

1. Your headers should appear as the following:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="ar">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
   ```
2. Save your document as **utf-8**