# Problems with characters in url

Tags: php

i have two simple page:

```
(first.php)
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<form action="second.php"  method="post"  accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=">>"  id="submit" />

</html>

(second.php)
<?php
header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$url=$_GET['search'];
$url= urlencode($_GET['search']);
echo $url

?>

output in second.php:

%C8%E1%ED%C8%E1%C8
```

> > > > > the question: how can i return same arabic character in second.php

thank you 4 you'r Patience

Comment: Please read summat like http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp and change the character set that the browser observes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303255/encoding-arabic-using-utf8

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

I modified the second.php for you ,I test it and it's work fine with arabic words
You don't need to use urlencode function again.

```
<?php

 header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
 $url=$_GET['search'];
 $url= $_GET['search'];
 echo $url

?>
```

Comment: i do it but no change

Comment: Could you send to me source code of destination page?